# Include sys.databases name as column in dynamic SQL UNION

Tags: sql, database, dynamic, union

I have successfully written code to dynamically union the results of a simple select statement across multiple databases.  I would like to include the database name itself as a field so that I can identify each record.  What is the best way to modify the code below to accomplish that?

My current results look like

field2, field3, field4
b,c,d
2,3,4

I can't tell what database the row containing (b,c,d) comes from.

And I would like to make sure I see
field1, field2, field3, field4
First_DatabaseName, b,c,d
Second_DatabaseName,2,3,4

And above, I could then see that the row containing (b,c,d) comes from First_Database

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)

SELECT @sql = ISNULL(@sql + 'union all ',' ') + ' SELECT * FROM ' + name + '.dbo.CombinedProvider '
FROM   sys.databases
WHERE  name in ('First_DatabaseName', 'Second_DatabaseName')

EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Do you need to use the Select * or can you explicitly list the columns of each database?

Comment: I can explicitly list each column that I want from the table.  I only include * for sample purposes and will not be using that in production queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the name into the subquery that you are using:

```
SELECT @sql = COALESCE(@sql + 'union all ',' ') + ' SELECT '''+name+''' as dbname, c.* FROM ' + name + '.dbo.CombinedProvider c'
FROM   sys.databases
WHERE  name in ('First_DatabaseName', 'Second_DatabaseName')
```

By the way, you are using an unsupported technique to do aggregate string concatenation.  You might want to learn about "for xml path('')" as an alternative technique.  Check out http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/ for more information than you want to know on this subject.

Comment: This solves it!  When I tried adding the name initially, I must have made a syntax error.  Thanks for pointing out the xml path link.  I'll study it and incorporate it into my future work.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'AS' after each column and include the source db name in the column.

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)

SELECT @sql = ISNULL(@sql + 'union all ',' ') + ' SELECT ColName as [First_DatabaseName_ColName], ColName2 as [Second_DatabaseName_ColName2], FROM ' + name + '.dbo.CombinedProvider '
FROM   sys.databases
WHERE  name in ('First_DatabaseName', 'Second_DatabaseName')

EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but to be crystal clear, the database name or a reference to it is 'not' contained in the combinedrprovider table.  The databasename is in the sysdatabases table instead.  I am wanting to pull the 'name' field from sys.databases into each record.  The solution you provided above hardcodes the name of the database as a part of the field name (not as a record).  It also doesn't work because each field in your query has records from both databases but does not label as such.